# meaning of "reactionary feathers"

Tags: meaning, phrases

> A saviour arrives in the form of Imperator Furiosa, one of Joe’s de
>   facto generals and a trusted war-rig driver, who is planning to help
>   the warlord’s unwilling brides escape from the Citadel. **Though the
>   presence of a strong female lead has ruffled some more reactionary
>   feathers,** Charlize Theron’s Furiosa is brilliant as the film’s
>   fearsome centre of gravity, commanding the screen and dominating the
>   fight scenes. Max, who was the unrivalled principal in the previous
>   films, is surprisingly good at sharing the screen. This is partly
>   because he spends much of the movie saying nothing, and what he does
>   utter comes out in a voice rather like the unintelligible rumble Mr
>   Hardy brought to Bane in “The Dark Knight Rises”. "Each of us in our
>   own way was broken," he rasps. "It was hard to know who was more
>   crazy: me or everyone else." And it is partly because, having started
>   the film as a frenetic ball of survival instinct, he only blossoms
>   into something recognisably human—and comes into his own—at around the
>   hour mark.

I searched the meaning of the phrase "(ruffled some more) reactionary feathers";  but couldn't find its meaning.

I guess it means to spark controversies or to trigger noises.

Would you help me understand its meaning?

Comment: Ruffle: to disturb the smoothness or regularity of; ripple. Feather is used metaphorically and *to ruffle reactionary feathers means to disturb/annoy the reactionary spirit* as the wind may ruffle the feathers of a bird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[ruffle someone's feathers](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ruffle)** is an idiom

From Oxford:

> Cause someone to become annoyed or upset:
>
> *this sudden rise ruffled the feathers of the old guard*

You sentence modifies this a bit to indicate that the people who got upset were reactionaries.